# How could I create a Sonar Plugin to exhibit simple images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, sonarqube, jfreechart

I'm developing a Sonarqube plugin which is a PostJob that generates some simple charts stored in jpeg format using the JFreeChart library. Since I don't have any knowledge on Rails web-development (and ruby language neither) I got stucked when it comes to show that generated images on the project dashboard (in a widget).

I tried to follow [Deor's tutorial](https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/sonarqube-plugins-2/) in which he shows the method

```
 image_tag(url_for_static(:plugin => 'idemetadata', :path => 'check-round-yes-small.png'), :size => '16x16', :style => 'vertical-align:middle')
```

but it seems that this method only allows to show images which are stored under /static folder in the plugin .jar file.

All I need is a way of exhibiting images stored into my local filesystem (which are generated by the PostJob extension I mentioned). Could someone please give me a clue on how to do that?

Thank you all in advance!
Jefferson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using standard html tags?

```
<img src="PATH">
```

I developed a widget that shows graphics from graphite. It works fine with the html tags.

Comment: Have you developed the widget you've mentioned for Sonarqube ? I tried using the standard html img tag in many ways but it just didn't work. It seems that Ruby doesn't allow access to files outside it is server for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, it's a widget for a sonar plugin (erb.html file). 
I assemble the link for the graphic in ruby and just use it inside the img-tags. The graphic is on a different machine (although its accessible via HTTP; I don't need to access a filesystem, maybe thats the key difference)
Have you checked the resulting html code?

Comment: After reading your solution I found a way of solving this problem. Basically I store the images generated into the sonar web aplication directory, then it becomes acessible in the http manner you've just mentioned. Thanks a lot man!